# could not load type submit symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a newbie on Symfony and I have some problems with the 3thd version.  I created a formType with the console called userType.  Everything is ok but I can't add a submit button.  The old way `->add('save','submit')` is not working and I think it's about the version of symfony.  So, here is my code :

```html
<?php

namespace MyBundle\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class userType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('nickname')
            //->add('dateOfBirth', 'date')
            ->add('sex')
            ->add('country')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task')); //here is the problem
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\UserBundle\Entity\user'
        ));
    }
}
```

Have you got an idea about how to resolve that problem ?  Sorry if I'm posting in the wron section :-).

Thank's for having read me,

Axel

Comment: Define 'not working'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use correct namespace:

```
namespace MyBundle\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType; // ← this line
```

Comment: Yes I did it and it works.  I have already done that but it wasn't working due to a syntax problem...  well thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

As stated on page 27 of the book ['Best practices for Symfony 3'](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_best_practices_3.0.pdf) you can find that this is not changed.

> **Form Button Configuration**
>
> Form classes should try to be agnostic to where they will be used.
>   This makes them easier to re-use later. Add buttons in the templates,
>   not in the form classes or the controllers. Since Symfony 2.3, you can
>   add buttons as fields on your form. This is a nice way to simplify the
>   template that renders your form. But if you add the buttons directly
>   in your form class, this would effectively limit the scope of that
>   form.

```
$builder
   // ...
   ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you ;-) and "create post" is really funny, it makes me laught.  So, you're answer is really helpfull because at least I know that's not a version problem.

Comment: Hum, I've just seen that the "Create Post" wasn't really a joke, it's in the doc, anyway, it was funny

Comment: Glad you've had a laugh ;-)